# Populate JQuery DataTables from PHP Json Object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

i'm trying to populate my table ([DataTables.net](https://datatables.net)) using ajax. The received values are from an json object generated by my php script. For the moment i can manage it by using classic method, vars from php but i want to switch to json method now.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfL8x7sf/) where i have tested many things without any success :\

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUCyQgmGeW?indent=2",
        "dataSrc": "syncok"
      },
      "columns": [
        { "data": "Ticket_RT" },
        { "data": "Last_up_time" },
        { "data": "Last_down_time" },
        { "data": "Date_du_Diag" },
        { "data": "Commentaire_FT" },
        { "data": "Code_Retour_FT" },
        { "data": "Supprimer" }
      ]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div id="exampleDiv">hello</div>
<table width="100%" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket RT</th>
      <th>Last up time</th>
      <th>Date du Diag RT</th>
      <th>Commentaire FT</th>
      <th>Code Retour FT</th>
      <th>Supprimer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem, i have tried many snippet from stackoverflow and from the original documentation but i can't manage it by myself !

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Regards.

**EDIT :**

To fix this issue you must add this before .DataTable function :
`$("#example").empty();`

And add an option `"bDestroy": true,` to .DataTable function.

Solution from this thread : [DataTables Forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21616/typeerror-headercells-i-is-undefined-when-re-creating-table)

**EDIT 2 :**

Excuse me i'm blind ! Now my title disappear after adding .empty() function...
Now i'm trying to fix this another problem, so if someone can put me in the right way ! Thank you in advance for the help :)

**FIX :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ret_syncok").empty();
$('#ret_syncok').DataTable( {
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "js/optionsTables/cMass_ret_syncok.php",
        "dataSrc": "syncok"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Ticket_RT" },
        { "data": "Last_up_time" },
        { "data": "Last_down_time" },
        { "data": "Date_du_Diag_RT" },
        { "data": "Commentaire_FT" },
        { "data": "Code_Retour_FT" },
        { "data": "Supprimer" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        { "title": "Ticket RT", "targets": 0 },
        { "title": "Last up time", "targets": 1 },
        { "title": "Last down time", "targets": 2 },
        { "title": "Date du Diag_RT", "targets": 3 },
        { "title": "Commentaire FT", "targets": 4 },
        { "title": "Code Retour FT", "targets": 5 },
        { "title": "Supprimer", "targets": 6 }
    ]
});
});
```

I hope that can help someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not working in Jsfiddle since Ajax url is http not https,

I tried in my computer and it's working.
Problem was-
column's names was not same.
Number of columns were not same.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<div id="exampleDiv">hello</div>
<table width="100%" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket RT</th>
      <th>Last up time</th>
      <th>Last down time</th>
      <th>Date du Diag RT</th>
      <th>Commentaire FT</th>
      <th>Code Retour FT</th>
      <th>Supprimer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
      "ajax": {
    "url": "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUCyQgmGeW?indent=2",
    "dataSrc": "syncok"
      },
      "columns": [
    { "data": "Ticket_RT" },
    { "data": "Code_Retour_FT" },
    { "data": "Date_du_Diag_RT" },
    { "data": "Last_up_time" },
    { "data": "Supprimer" },
    { "data": "Last_down_time" },
    { "data": "Commentaire_FT" }
      ]
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: well i don't understand what happen to the json code but in my computer is well structured.

Here is another test from Live dataTables : http://live.datatables.net/panudoro/1/edit and that works great. Very strange.

Message error from console log : 
**TypeError: headerCells[i] is undefined**

Comment: I think Column names in Json are different in different countries due to language difference.